# I get an error when trying to run my code

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I am trying to make this program which has 5 entry boxes, which need to save what ever there has been put into the boxes when you click a button and save it to a .txt file.

```
    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
}

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string tb1Text = tb1.Text;
    string tb2Text = tb2.Text;
    string tb3Text = tb3.Text;
    string tb4Text = tb4.Text;
    string tb5Text = tb5.Text;

    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/Home/Desktop/Test.txt")) {
        sw.WriteLine(tb1Text + Environment.NewLine + tb2Text + Environment.NewLine + tb3Text + Environment.NewLine + tb4Text + Environment.NewLine + tb5Text);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I get the error "Unexpected symbol 'end-of-file'" at second to last line of code.

Comment: Look at your braces.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra curly brace on the StreamWriter line. Either do

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/Home/Desktop/Test.txt"))
     sw.WriteLine(..);
```

or

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/Home/Desktop/Test.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(..);
}
```

Btw. you may want to look into String.Join() method and you may get rid of the " + NewLine" code. `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, tb1.Text,tb2.Text etc....)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use consistent style in your code, sometimes you put the brace on the next line, sometimes you put it on the same line. Choose one style (the first one is more widespread) and stick with it.

```
protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
```

When a block of code is a oneliner, like your last line of code, you can omit the braces :

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/Home/Desktop/Test.txt"))
    sw.WriteLine(tb1Text + Environment.NewLine + tb2Text + Environment.NewLine + tb3Text + Environment.NewLine + tb4Text + Environment.NewLine + tb5Text);
```

is equivalent to :

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/Home/Desktop/Test.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(tb1Text + Environment.NewLine + tb2Text + Environment.NewLine + tb3Text + Environment.NewLine + tb4Text + Environment.NewLine + tb5Text);
}
```

Your problem is that you had only one of those braces in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/Home/Desktop/Test.txt")) {
```

You have a problem in this line. Change the code as

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\username\\Home\\Desktop\\Test.txt")) {
```

Its all basics, the path that window's shows is different from the path specified on the language. Program considers "/"  as a simple character which in turn it treats as single filename. Meanwhile "\" is a special character and it can clearly differntiate the path; so it has to done a little bit different.